# Prove that a set of sequences in $l^{2}$ whose sum of squares is bounded by 1 is an open subset of $l^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Note: Please excuse my poor notation. I only know how to write some symbols in this software, and not very consistently. I hope how I've presented things still makes it clear enough. If you wish to edit this notation, or reference me to a notation guide, then please feel free.

I am taking Real Analysis 2 and studying from the book "Methods of Real Analysis" by Richard R. Goldberg. I am having trouble with exercise 7 from section 5.4. The question states:

**Let $A$ be the set of all sequences $\{s_n\} \in l^2$ such that the sum of all $(s_n)^2$ is less than $1$. Prove that $A$ is an open subset of $l^2$. Assume the standard metric for $l^2$. That is, that $d(x,y)=\sqrt{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x_n- y_n)^2}$.**

Using the open ball definition of an open set, I tried to show that for all $a\in A$, there exists an $r \gt 0$ such that, for all $x \in l^2, 0 \lt d(a,x) \lt r$ implies that $x \in A$, therefore showing that $B[a,r]$ is a subset of $A$ by definition. However, I couldn't get the inequalities to work, nor could I find what $r$ would be in the first place. I also briefly tried to do a proof by contradiction, showing that for all $r \gt 0$, there exists $x \in l^2$ such that $x \in B[a,r]$ and $x \notin A$. However, I had similar issues getting the inequalities to work and finding a construction for such an $x$ (from which the contradiction would likely come).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure if I'm simply not being smart with my triangle and schwartz inequalities, or if my general approach to the problem is just wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Your approach is correct.  If $s=\sum x_n^2 \lt 1$, then $s=1-t$ for some $t \gt 0$.  Choose $\varepsilon = \frac t3$ and use the triangle inequality to show that $d(x, y) \lt \varepsilon \Rightarrow \sum y_n^2 \lt 1$.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you! It feels so obvious now, I just wasn't thinking to rewrite s in terms of epsilon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler way is to realize for any normed vector space $(X,\| \cdot \|)$, the map $x \in X \rightarrow \|x \| \in \mathbb{R_{+}}$ is continuous by the triangle inequality
$$ | \|x \| - \| y \| | \leq \|x - y \|$$
Now since $[0,1)$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R_{+}}$ and $\| \cdot \|$ is continuous, the inverse image of $[0,1)$, which is the set $A$, is open.